# PayPal API SSL Issue - just started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, ssl-certificate

We've just started receiving the following error when trying to process PayPal payments on our production system.
Our system hasn't been recently updated so the issue is not our code base.

The error is reporting as:
'''
An OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError occurred in memberships#pay_renewal:

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
'''

I'm at a loss to know where to begin with this.

The application is running Ruby on Rails v6.0.2, using paypal-sdk-rest gem (v 1.7.4), and running on an Amazon EC2 Redhat instance.

I suspect its to do with new certificates needed to be installed somewhere on our server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who are looking for an immediate solution, here is a bit more technical details on top of the information @preston-phx and @houdi provided:

As mentioned on Paypal's article: https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/migration-to-digicert-root-certificates-ts2240

Download the "DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA" and "DigiCert Global Root G2" certificates from Digicert here:

https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm

Also, download certificates for all Paypal APIs you are making calls to from:

https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/ts1510

(In my case, I only use api.paypal.com so I downloaded api.paypal.com.pem and api.sandbox.paypal.com.pem)

These will give you a set of pem files like:

```
DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem
DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt.pem
api.paypal.com.pem
api.sandbox.paypal.com.pem
```

Merge all your files to a single paypal.crt file, which will look like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
...
```

Put the file somewhere in your project. I put it under `data/paypal.crt` similar to where the PayPal-Ruby-SDK stores it.

Now you can monkey patch the SDK to use your paypal.crt file instead of the ouut-dated one provided in the SDK by adding the following snippet somewhere before where you initialize your PayPal SDK:

```
# Monkey patch the paypal certificate file
PayPal::SDK::Core::Util::HTTPHelper.class_eval do
  def default_ca_file
    File.expand_path("../../data/paypal.crt", __dir__)
  end 
end
```

I'm using Rails so I added that directly to the top of my config/initializers/paypal.rb file.

(I'm not providing any direct links to the certificates or the certificates themselves here because you should never trust any certificate provided by a third-party. Download all certificates directly from PayPal and Digicert sites)

Answer (score 4):

Your suspicions are correct, make sure you are trusting the DigiCert roots (High Assurance EV and Global G2) as the cutoff was made recently for api.paypal.com -- many notifications were sent about this

Some details here: https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/migration-to-digicert-root-certificates-ts2240

Comment: Thanks for this. I've downloaded the certificates and when installing on RedHat EC2 it warned that they were duplicates so would appear they are already installed.

Comment: Yeah well they're not being used by the code path giving that error

Comment: I've tracked down where the ruby gem installs its own Digi... certificates and replaced them. I also commented out the use of a paypal.crt file included within the gem. As a result our system is now linking once more to PayPal. Unfortunately the gem is deprecated so I'll have to fork it and make some local changes. Thanks for your pointers - very useful :-)

Comment: The future (well, present actually) is the v2 Checkout-Ruby-SDK used in two routes, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ , and paired with this front-end UI that keeps your site loaded (no redirects) : https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server